# Will I be able to install the latest version of Chromium or Firefox on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I need to run WebRTC with Chromium or Firefox on Raspberry Pi v2 (ordered, I don't have it yet).

WebRTC requires a recent version of Chromium to be able to run i.e. `> v33.0`

Considering that [**armel** and **armhf** where removed from Debian Wheezy since March 2013](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-chromium/pkg-chromium.git/commit/?id=8761d73), I was wondering if that is also true for the Raspbian distribution.

If Chromium isn't supported, does Raspbian support latest Firefox browser?

To test is a browser supports WebRTC, you can browse to https://opentokrtc.com/ ... I fear that the latest Chromium available on Raspbian doesn't support WebRTC.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-chromium

Comment: Firefox 35.0.1 is in [Fedora 21 for ARM](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/can-i-use-fedora-on-the-pi-2).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer:

Firefox is named Iceweasel in Debian and is in the Raspbian repository. You can install it just by typing the following command in terminal/tty:

```
sudo apt-get install iceweasel
```

Comment: The following NEW packages will be instaled: iceweasel. Then got error Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/weezy/main icewasel armhf 31.4.0esr-1-deb7ul+rpil 404 Not Found Failed to fetch E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: have you tried running sudo apt-get update?

Comment: Although currently the `iceweasel` package still exists in transition, as of spring '16 this distinction is [no longer meaningful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_software_rebranded_by_Debian) and `firefox` is included as is in Debian/Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest version of Chromium [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=121195).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Good news. Chromium installs without problem.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Tested on a B+ with the latest Raspbian distro

Hmm... Maybe not. Version listed is 22.0.1229.94

EDIT: Image below of Chrome at opentokrtc.com

[image]

Does this mean it works?

EDIT: EDIT: After adding a room it doesn't appear to be responding correctly. However, I wasn't able to get it to respond in a way that I thought with Chrome version 40.0.2214.115 on my desktop. I'm afraid that the jury is out for me. Chromium will install, but the version looks to be too early. I was not able to confirm operation.

Comment: yeah that's what I feared. A quick test for WebRTC support is to browse to https://opentokrtc.com/

Comment: I've edited the post to include the screenshot of the browser at opentokrtc.org. It appears to be working?

Comment: you need to start a room, if your video starts then it works. Enter a string e.g. testwebrtc then click `Join`