# How to click on browser page while emulating touch with Chromium

Tags: touchscreen, emulation, chromium

I needed to simulate touch screen device on Raspberry, and there are some issues installing the driver. So, as a workaround, I'm using Chromium for that purpose with `--simulate-touch-screen-with-mouse` flag:

```
chromium --simulate-touch-screen-with-mouse http://my-site.com
```

It perfectly simulates scrolling, but clicks are not working in the page. How can I make the clicks (and right clicks) work?

Chromium version is 22.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Chrome/Chromium needs to be set up to use touch devices - their are a varying set of solutions [over on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471513/chrome-touchscreen-unity-14-04):

- *Run chrome with options to use the touch device*:

  Run it with:

  ```
  google-chrome --touch-devices=10
  ```

  Where `10` is the ID of the touchscreen (possibly noted by ``) in `xinput list`

  Other available helpful options are `--touch-events=enabled` & `--enable-pinch` - more options are available [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). You may not need to modify the command line arguments directly if you add `export CHROMIUM_USER_FLAGS="--touch-devices=10"` to your `~/.profile`.
- *Enable a flag*:

  Navigate to `chrome://flags/#touch-events` and set it to enabled

This may not be needed [in newer Chrome versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620332/chrome-43-touchscreen-ubuntu-15-04), but these are probably unavailable on the Pi: [How can I install the latest version of Chromium?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/how-can-i-install-the-latest-version-of-chromium)

Comment: There is no luck with all above flags, maybe I should install the latest version of Chromium... Thank you, I'll be back.